# How to train a LSTM with a multivarible input of different lengths?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a Keras LSTM model based on sensor data detecting a fall.

There are multiple trials all in one dataframe containig different lengths of timeseries with sensory data (X-axis,Y-axis and Z-axis), so each trial has an output something like this:

```
[[1,4,7],[1,5,3],[5,2,7],[7,2,5],[9,5,2].......]
```

But I can't find a way to deal with the varying lengths of the inputs. The output has to be in 1 dimension. Just is it a fall or not. How to do this?

Comment: did you consider padding ?

Comment: The concept is called padding: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding You only pad inputs, your outputs are fine as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Keras LSTM takes input [batch, timesteps, feature] as described [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/). As I understand, you have 3 features (columns) and rows as data flow (time series, sequential). So, input dimensions depends on your configuration.
For example:

```
features = 3
timesteps = 20
batch = 1
```

This configuration means that LSTM input takes 3 features with 20 timesteps.It takes every 20 row of 3 features together. So, if you have a dataframe with 2D, you have to reshape it to 3D.

Let's say you have a pandas dataframe with 100 timesteps and 3 features (100,3):
You can reshape it  to 3D like:

```
data = np.array(data).reshape(-1,20,3)
```

So, new data shape is (5,20,3)